# Quantum field theory being deformation of conformal field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory

I read it somewhere in physics SE that quantum field theory is today considered as deformation of conformal field theory. What does that mean?

Comment: Without the context, this claim sounds absurd, sorry.

Comment: The idea might be that by rescaling a QFT you reach a renormalization group fixed point; that fixed point is scale-invariant and therefore in many cases conformally invariant; then can we recover the original QFT by deforming that CFT? This is how I would understand the question, but I do not know the answer. Anyway it is no more absurd to consider QFT as a deformation of CFT, than to consider QFT as a deformation of free QFT.

Comment: See also this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/339309/why-can-consistent-qfts-only-arise-from-cfts

Comment: See, for example, the introduction to [1602.07982](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982) or [1601.05000](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05000)